# win.js.ui.HtmlControl: 'element' is not defined.? whats this error.?

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I used `WinJS.UI.HtmlControl object` for my app and I initialized this using `JavaScript` code as below. But It shows error that `element` is not defined.

My JavaScript code:

```
var object = new WinJS.UI.HtmlControl(element, {uri: 'page.html'});
```

Error:

```
SCRIPT5009: Unhandled exception at line 61, column 9 in
ms-appx://app-package.app-name/js/data.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'element' is undefined
File: data.js, Line: 61, Column: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is telling you that the variable named 'element' in your call is not defined anywhere. That argument needs to be set to whatever element in the DOM will host the HtmlControl.

For example, if you have this in your markup:

```
<div id="contentHost"></div>
```

Then in your code you'd do this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("contentHost");
var object = new WinJS.UI.HtmlControl(element, {uri: 'page.html'});
```

This element is required because the HtmlControl needs to know where in the DOM to load up page.html, otherwise nothing would ever show.